# Where can I find data on GDP of US counties?

Tags: data-request, usa, county, gdp

I am looking for data on the total GDP of most or all United States counties. (GDP per capita is fine too, I can multiply it by population). I am not sure if this data exists, but I know there are definitely sub-national statistics on GDP, for example, there is data on GDP of each individual state and for most Metro Areas in the country.

Also, income and GDP are different. [This wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_United_States_counties_by_per_capita_income) is the closest thing I've been able to find, but it lists counties by their income per capita, not GDP per capita. You can tell, because they have it listed per state as well, and if you multiply the income per capita by population, it doesn't come anywhere close to the [state GDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_U.S._states_by_GDP) for most states.

Comment: **A Research Agenda for Measuring GDP at the County Level** (https://bea.gov/papers/pdf/BEA%20WP_Research%20Agenda%20for%20GDP%20County.pdf) dated July 2016 suggests that this doesn't exist yet.

Comment: @BarryCarter I thought that might be the case. Thanks for looking.

Comment: @philshem Yeah, that's a fair point, I will do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### BEA: GDP by County, Metro, and Other Areas

The Bureau of Economic Analysis released the first official GDP estimates for the county level in December 2019:[¹](https://www.bea.gov/news/blog/2019-11-21/first-official-county-gdp-stats-coming-dec-12)

- ["GDP by County, Metro, and Other Areas" on BEA.gov](https://www.bea.gov/data/gdp/gdp-county-metro-and-other-areas)

Answer (score 3):

County profiles at [NACO Count Explorer](https://ce.naco.org/?find=true) have county-level GDP data. The most current data at this time is 2016.

Answer (score 1):

Woods & Poole provide GDP for all U.S. counties.  Unfortunately, they are a private, for-profit firm and consequently, the data has to be purchased.   I would like to have had the database for all counties as well, but it was not necessary for my current research.

Their link is below.  Finally, I would suggest reaching out to them and letting them know what you are working on.  A couple of years ago, I did that and they provided the data I needed free of charge!

https://www.woodsandpoole.com/our-databases/united-states/single-variable/#products-list